# Responsive Site Not Working on iPad

Tags: media-queries, responsive-design

I'm in the process of creating my own framework and have been looking at other boilerplates to see how it is done.

I'm currently looking at [this](http://demo.mattbrett.com/bare-bones-stylesheet/) bare bones stylesheet and was wondering why it seems to act responsive when you resize the browser, but when I open it on my iPhone or iPad it displays the full screen version of the site.

Sorry if this is noob question, I'm still trying to wrap my head around media queries (no pun intended).

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:** Silly me, I forgot to add the meta tag to tell devices like the iPad to set the device width to the size of its viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Comment: You'll want to post that edit as an answer instead, then mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Silly me, I forgot to add the meta tag to tell devices like the iPad to set the device width to the size of its viewport.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```