# Site not responsive on IPAD, media queries not working

Tags: html, css, ipad, media-queries

I have an issue, the website I build is responsive on phones but is not on IPAD

This is the media query I am using :

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {
..
}
```

and at the top of my templates after the doctype declaration I have :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Can someone help me out please ?

Thank you !

Comment: First check you are using proper queries..

Comment: Maybe this helps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568827/responsive-site-not-working-on-ipad?rq=1

Comment: I had a look at this already thank you.

Comment: oh...try giving us a bit more info? Can you post more of your code? Can you link us to the site? Anything?

Comment: Does it work on other iPads or just not the mini? Also, the mini's screen is 768px wide, as such, none of the code you put in that particular `@media` statement will apply to the iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change this:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 767px)
```

to this:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 768px)
```

Since the iPad screen is 768 pixels wide.

Comment: It still doesn't work. I am really confused about what's going on . It works fine on Iphone, browser resizing, android devices. Just not ipads ..

Comment: Are you holding the iPad vertically?

Comment: Yes I am indeed. If I was holding the sony tablet vertically it would work .

Comment: So...did this fix it for you in the end? Don't leave us hanging! :)

Comment: It did fix it indeed. The other issue was that for whatever reason that is, the viewport scale was wrong on a site:head include on the website. Wich was just wrong ..

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1200px)  
{
    // Your code here
}
```